# Big text data in php array

Tags: php, mysql, json

The goal of my code is to return all the db table in JSON format. But i can't do it! Everytime I get empty web-page! Here is my code:

```
$response["result"] = array();
$res = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM table_lessons") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $response["version"] = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $res["id"] = $row["id"];
            $res["band"] = $row["band"];
            $res["title"] = $row["title"];
            $res["category"] = $row["category"];
            $res["address"] = $row["address"];
            $res["song_text"] = $row["song_text"];
            $res["song_text_chords"] = $row["song_text_chords"];
            $res["provider"] = $row["provider"];
            array_push($response["result"], $res);
        }
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
```

I've trying to push only "id" field, and it works! I think there is problem with `$res["song_text"]` - it is big TEXT field...

`var_dump($response);` prints full array, with all fields...

Thanks!

I just realized that when I try to print separate row in while block such as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $res["id"] = $row["id"];
            $res["band"] = $row["band"];
            $res["title"] = $row["title"];
            $res["category"] = $row["category"];
            $res["address"] = $row["address"];
            $res["song_text"] = $row["song_text"];
            $res["song_text_chords"] = $row["song_text_chords"];
            $res["provider"] = $row["provider"];

            echo json_encode($row);

            array_push($response["result"], $res);
        }
```

shows only fields where are no cyrillic letters... is that the reason?

Comment: Can you please make sure error reporting is reporting all errors?

Comment: @Scopey reporting all errors just returns `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`

Comment: @tastro returns `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`... I've changed it to `echo json_encode($response[1]);` - same result

Comment: @Class yeah, I've tried it. I have put `echo json_encode($row);` in while block, and it returns all row separately, with all data